# raid 1 always degraded after pushing reset

Tags: software-raid, hardware-raid, raid1

I have Marvell hardware raid 1.

After pushing reset or any other incorrect shutdown raid is degraded.

Is it possible to create hardware raid 1 on other chips(intel chipset for example) for example or software raid 1 such that it is not degraded after reset?

For software raid windows solutions are preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal that a RAID (hw or sw) gets degraded after a reset. It just needs that the data is not written exactly simultaneously on both devices for this to happen: this is a race condition. If you push reset just on the moment in which both disk have been written to a different extent, you'll get a degraded condition since the RAID system will need to deem one of them out-of-sync.

This, together with the possible problems with the filesystem itself, gives you the golden rule: avoid hard resets.

Comment: +1 EXCEPT: Hardware Raid: NO. A real hardware raid is not making a dirty reset just because the computer makes it. Heck, a "real" raid controller even is not degraded after a power failure because he has a battery or flash backed up cache on the card. But especially software just gets degraded when you press reset because there is no way to avoid that short of being VERY carefull (thus slow) with writes.